# Make changes in the Excel Workbook that open my query

Tags: excel

I'm a TFS2010 User.

I have my own query named "My Current job" that show me the User Stories and related Task that I have to do right now.

I have opened the query in excel and made a conditional format to the workbook that show in green color the rows of completed work items.

Are there any way to make this conditional format (and other changes like this) permanent for this query?

I'm not the only one user of the teamproject, so I preffer don't change anything that could affect others users unless that is the only way.

Currently I've excel macros that do the job, but I wonder if it can be done directly in TFS .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible by using the "Team" ribbon on any Excel-document, simply click on any cell and then select "New List". 
Navigate to the query you 're interested in and harvest the results in your worksheet:
[image]
Once you have established this link "Publish" will push your changes from Excel to TFS and "Refresh" will refresh your results from TFS

Comment: Yes, when I click Publish the changes in the workitems are saved, but not the conditional format (that make green my closed tasks rows). So next time I open the query the changes in the conditional format aren't there.

Comment: You have one Excel-file "MyQuery.xls", that gets results from TFS and has been somehow customized by you. If you keep this Excel file and continue using it with "Refresh" & "Publish", your formatting changes should be preserved. I tried with your scenario (Conditional Formatting) and, at least for me, it worked fine.

Comment: It's not possible to resolve this issue as a TFS-query setting.

Comment: So the key is to save the xls in my HD, because the file is linked to TFS, and use the file directly instead of open it directly from the query. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Yes, another possibly better, option is to have the TFS query work with `Assigned To = @Me` and then upload it in Sharepoint. That way it can be useful to more members of your team.